# How to show/hide sidenav on trigger button click in materialize

Tags: jquery

I want to be able to close sidenav when clicking on trigger button on small screen. Im using materialize 1.00 and Jquery 3.3.1. Right now im only able to click outside to close it

Here is my HTML

```
<nav class="nav-wrapper">
  <a href="#" data-target="nav-mobile" class="top-nav sidenav-trigger 
    waves-effect waves-light circle hide-on-large-only">
   <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
 </a>
</nav>
```

....

Here is part of my js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.sidenav').sidenav();
});
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.button-collapse').sideNav({
      closeOnClick: true // Closes side-nav on <a> clicks, useful for Angular/Meteor
    }
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<nav class="red lighten-1" role="navigation">
  <div class="nav-wrapper container">

    <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
      <li><a href="#">Navbar Link</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="nav-mobile" class="side-nav" style="transform: translateX(-100%);">
      <li><a href="#">Navbar Link</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" data-activates="nav-mobile" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. unfortunately, it didn't fix the issue :(